# virtualenv: same version of BeautifulSoup returns different results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a beautifulSoup installed one in general Python path and another in virtualenv

```
beautifulsoup4  - 4.1.3        - active  # in general Python installation
```

and

```
beautifulsoup4  - 4.1.3        - active # in virtualenv path
```

I run the following code in both the environments

```
import urllib2
import unicodedata
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.thehindu.com/news/cities/bangalore/aero-india-takes-off-on-february-6/article4329776.ece').fp)
```

In general Python installation, it gives me

```
>>> soup.select('.article-text .body')
[<p class="body"> It is that time when aviation buffs get ready to take off to the Air Force Station in Yelahanka here when the ninth edition of Aero India will be inaugurated by Defence Minister A.K. Antony on February 6.</p>, <p class="body">They can watch aerobatics by, among others, the Flying Bulls from the Czech Republic and Russian Knights — the Russian Air Force Aerobatic Team will complement Indian Air Force’s Sarang Aerobatic Team — at the biennial event that provides a platform for Indian and foreign vendors.</p>, <p class="body">However, IAF’s pride — the Surya Kiran Aerobatic Tea — which has performed to huge plaudits from the audience in the previous shows, will not be there for the country’s premier air show, a press release said.</p>, <p class="body">All exhibition space has been sold out and this edition is expected to see the participation of over 600 companies and 768 overseas delegations. </p>, <p class="body">The largest overseas participation is from the U.S. followed by Israel and Russia. The other major participants include France, the U.K., Germany and Belgium, Bulgaria, Italy, Ukraine, Australia, Belarus, Czech Republic, Japan, Norway, South Africa, Spain, Switzerland, Austria, Brazil, Canada, The Netherlands, Romania, Sweden, Singapore and the UAE.</p>, <p class="body">Organised by the Department of Defence Production, the five-day show aims at promoting products and services being offered by the Indian Defence industry in the international market.</p>]
>>>
```

while in virtualenv environment, it shows nothing

```
>>> soup.select('.article-text .body')  
[]
```

What is causing this problem? How do I fix it in virtual env?

Comment: if the code is the same, and the BS version is the same, and i assume the file is the same.. you need to find what is different. you have not given enough information for us to help you do this. maybe try this on smaller file sample you can post here, and also give us the specs of each environment.

Comment: did you check if the same content is being returned for both of the `urllib2.urlopen` calls?

Comment: @dm03514 good point! yes, i just realized you are not using a URL opener, and some sites return differently structured HTML depending on the user agent, each environment might be using a different user agent.

Comment: good points, let me check on that first

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of this problem is that [one environment has a parser library installed which the other lacks](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems). Check for that.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this same problem. The solution that worked for me was to explicitly indicate the parser. In my case this was:
`soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html5lib")`